# Button to load new screen but staying on one page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

Okay so I am trying to accomplish what these photos show. I want to be able to go from list, which is a view with a white background that has some content to when clicked on map, it does not necessarily change pages, but it does load this screen of a map.

What is the best way to go about doing this for react native? I tried googling around but could not find much, it was hard to google for.

Thank you guys, I appreciate it more than you know.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you load the new content?

Comment: There are probably several methods to accomplish this. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Domino987 I load the new content through a stack. Traveling through the stack with buttons. Drew Reese I have not tried anything yet. I do not have an idea to go about doing it

Comment: Well, since you want to "stay on the same page" then likely you are looking for [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) as an easy lo-fi solution, but certainly could also be achieved using navigation packages as well, or others. It depends on your existing code structure and familiarity what you want to use. As-is this question is too broad and open to opinionated answers, try to narrow the focus of your query to a more specific topic/issue.

Comment: Okay noted. Thank you for the insight. I will look into these!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be asking about how to conditionally render something. You can render components based on the value of another variable. Something like this.

```
  const [viewMode, setViewMode] = useState('list');

  const handleShowListPress = () => {
    setViewMode('list');
  };

  const handleShowMapPress = () => {
    setViewMode('map');
  };

  ...

  return (
     <View>
        <ListButton onPress={handleShowListPress} />
        <MapButton onPress={handleShowMapPress} />

        {viewMode === 'list' && <ListView />}
        {viewMode === 'map' &&  <MapView />}
     </View>
  );
```